# Change font-size with orientationchange

Tags: html, angular, sass, ionic2

I am trying to change the font size so it changes with the orientation and recalculates based on the screen width.
How can i change the font size when the orientation changes between landscape and portrait? I have tried an event listener but it doesn't change the size.

Typescript code

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public fontSize: any;

  constructor(private navController: NavController) {



    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", this.setFontSize, false);

  }


  public setFontSize() {

        this.fontSize = screen.with * 0.059375;

    }
  }



}
```

HTML code

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    teste
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home" padding>
  <p [ngStyle]="{'font-size': fontSize + 'px'}">TEXT</p>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Throw away the javascript, and just use CSS:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
 p { font-size: 20px; }
}
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  p { font-size: 10px; }
}
```

or use one as the default:

```
p { font-size: 20px; }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  p { font-size: 10px; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Robert but i need to recalculate the fontsize based on the screen width. I have edit the question. So that i don't have to make queries of all the available phone sizes on the market.